# TabControl Saving on selected tab item changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I need to save data in distinct `TabItem` every time when user switches to another tabitem.

I try to operate `TabControl.SelectionChanged` event, but there is no info about previously selected tab item.

So, how to get moment when user switches from my TabItem to another?

Comment: Use the Deselected event, e.TabPage gives you the reference you are looking for.  Or Deselecting if you have a reason to cancel it.

Comment: A WPF `TabControl` will re-use the `TabItem` Template if possible, so the actual Controls won't change but the `DataContext` behind the controls will change. If you want to save the data stored in the controls when switching tabs, you need to bind it to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a global variable to store what is the last tab

```
private TabPage LastTab = null;

private void tabSelectionChanged(...)
{
  if(LastTab != null)
     //Do save

  LastTab = tab.SelectedTabPage;// or equivalent 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the Enter and Leave events of the individual tabs. If you need the enter event to fire on code start up then you may need to programmatically change the selected tab to one that is different than at design time.

Comment: This is a terribly crude hack that should be avoided no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
private object LastTab = null;

private void tabSelectionChanged(...)
{
  if(LastTab != null)
  {
     //Do save
  }

  LastTab = control.SelectedContent;
}
```

Here the the content will be of type object you can type cast to specific class and do the save operation

Answer (score 0):

What you need exists in the parameter `SelectionChangedEventArgs e`:

- `e.AddedItems`
- `e.RemovedItems`